# Is this kind of $T$ injection correct?

Tags: circuit-construction, state-injection-model

I found the protocol in figure on internet, without proof.

[image]

Here, $|\omega\rangle = TH|0\rangle$.

It is refered as *catalytic injection*. I doubt its correctness on the second qubit as it outputs $|\omega\rangle$, no matter what $|\varphi\rangle$ is.

Is it correct?

Comment: what is $Z_{\pi/2}$?

Comment: $Z_{\pi/2} = S$, while $Z_{\pi/4} = T$

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote $|\varphi\rangle$ as:
$$|\varphi\rangle=a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$$
Thus, the system starts in the state:
$$(a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle)\otimes\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|1\rangle)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle+\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|01\rangle+\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}|10\rangle+\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|11\rangle$$
After having applied the first CNOT, the resulting state is:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle+\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|01\rangle+\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|10\rangle+\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle$$
We then apply the controlled-$S$ (note that this means applying a phase of $\frac\pi2$ to the state where both qubits are in state $1$):
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle+\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|01\rangle+\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|10\rangle+\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi2}|11\rangle=\left(a|0\rangle+b\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|1\rangle\right)\otimes\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\pi4}|1\rangle)=T|\varphi\rangle\otimes|\omega\rangle$$
Thus, this circuit is valid.

Comment: It is supposed to be a $T$ in the final equation, isn't it?

Comment: @DanieleCuomo Whoops, indeed, thanks for catching that!

Comment: Thus, it is straightforward to say that any noise on the first qubit doesn't propagate (assuming a perfect controlled-S), isn't it?

Comment: @DanieleCuomo any *pre-existing* error on $|\phi\rangle$ doesn't propagate on the second qubit (assuming the circuit is the correct one which seems so given Tristan's answer). However, if an error occurs between the first cNOT and the cS gate on the top qubit, it will typically induce an error on the second register.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to the usual circuit by the deferred measurement principle:

[image]

You can also see why it works by decomposing the CS gate into CNOT+T:

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Now that I look at the second picture I'm a bit confused though. As I don't get how come that (Pauli) noise (especially $X$) does not propagate in 2nd, 3rd and 4th part of the equivalence.

Comment: @DanieleCuomo Circuit manipulations don't always preserve noise propagation. For example, a CNOT controlled by a qubit that has just been reset can be added/deleted without changing the circuit, but this will change whether the reset failing flips just the reset qubit or also the qubit targeted by the CNOT.

Comment: I see. So far I used to think to noise propagation and post-processing operations as the same thing. But it seems not to be so. Is there a catalytic injection that allows you to push forward an X correction? I saw your talk where you show a T injection by means of 2 auxuliary qubits. Can that be catalytic and at the same time push an $X$ correction?

Comment: @DanieleCuomo I'm not sure what you mean by push forward an X correction. You mean you want an X before the be equivalent to an X after? That's impossible because the T gate rotates the X.

Comment: Ok, but maybe something it is still possible. For example, looking your previous answer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwlJc.png
One can perform the controlled-$S$ and then measure and the post-processing becomes $Z$ and $X$ condintioned on 2 different booleans. However, the auxiliary qubit can't be recycled.

Comment: @DanieleCuomo Maybe you should ask a separate question with what you actually want to do, which seems like some sort of fault tolerance thing to survive noise while using a T ancilla and access to CS gates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just posted one.
https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28490/pauli-propagation-through-state-injection-protocols